# Coordinate vector of w with respect to basis and with a zero row in the result

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

So I've got a simple 3x2 matrix whose columns are made up of two ordered basis vectors
\begin{pmatrix}3&2\\ \:1&-1\\ \:4&-3\end{pmatrix}

I've also got this vector w
\begin{pmatrix}-4\\ \:7\\ \:23\end{pmatrix}

Putting them together I get one augmented matrix where the rightmost column is vector w
RREF\begin{pmatrix}3&2&-4\\ \:\:\:\:\:1&-1&7\\ \:\:\:\:\:4&-3&23\end{pmatrix}

To find the solution I then found the REF of this matrix then decided to just the RREF since it was more convenient to look at the solution. This gives me an RREF of
\begin{pmatrix}1&0&2\\ 0&1&-5\\ 0&0&0\end{pmatrix}

from this I find the solution x1=2 and x2=-5. But row 3 is all zeros. The same thing occurs in just the REF form. So what is x3? is it zero? I know that usually something like this would result in infinitely many solutions

edit: There was definitely a logical failure here caused by the presence of the zero row. Would my solution just be x1=2 and x2=-5?

Comment: Your three rows correspond to equations in. two variables so this is what you should expect. I didn't check your math but your solution, if one exists, should only be two dimensional.

Comment: There isn't an $x_3$? The third column is the augmented column. You've got a system of three equations in two variables. My advice in the future: think before forming matrices out of vectors and row reducing. Ask yourself, why am I considering this system of linear equations? How do I interpret its solution (or lack thereof)? Knowing only shortcuts is a great way to get lost.

Comment: @JohnDouma so i would just say x1 and x2? Yeah I think I had a logical failure here when approaching this question. Still what does that zero row do? The solution should have 3 items in a vector, right?

Comment: @TheoBendit Yeah I screwed up big time there. Forgetting to put the  line separating the augmented part from the rest messed me up. The solution seems to require a vector with 3 values still. Would I have a vector like \begin{pmatrix}2\\ \:-5\\ \:0\end{pmatrix}

Comment: @ATR2400 No, the coordinate vector should be in $\Bbb{R}^2$, not $\Bbb{R}^3$. This is because $2$ is the number of elements in the basis, i.e. the dimension of the space.

Comment: @TheoBendit so just \begin{pmatrix}2\\ \:-5\end{pmatrix}

Comment: @ATR2400 Yes, that's right.

Comment: @TheoBendit Thanks! In retrospect I suppose that makes sense. Although the augmented matrix looks like a square the basis vectors put together are only 3x2